# As XNA is being retired, now what will be the official gaming platform for .NET developers?

Tags: .net, xna

[XNA is being retired](http://www.shacknews.com/article/77672/microsoft-xna-to-be-retired-casting-doubt-on-xbox-live). Now, as .NET will continue to be the standard for Windows and Windows Phone development, what is the standard for .NET game development?

Comment: Presumably DirectX/Direct3D?

Comment: Does DirectX/Direct3D have fully functional APIs for .NET developers?

Comment: DirectX/Direct3D is a native Library. There is no more managed wrapper for it. However, you can use C++/CLI to use in the same program, native code with managed code.

Comment: I would say http://unity3d.com/ would be a big alternative to XNA, I heard they have a partnership with microsoft for the windows 8 store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, now, Microsoft strategy is to support multiple languages and to use the most appropriate for each application. Indeed, each language has its benefits and drawbacks.

For example, C# is type-safe, has runtime checking, etc. But is slower in some cases and cannot be optimized on low level (SSE instruction, ...).

In most scenarios, games requires a lot more resources than common applications. Microsoft has then decided to drop XNA and Managed DirectX in favor of native DirectX. Also, to take the best from both sides, you have the solution C++/CLI, which supports managed and native programming in the same application and with the same language.

PS: You also have to keep in mind that Microsoft wants to go mobile! Resources on a mobile Platform are limited. Thus, even the "small" games for Windows Phone or tablets require to be optimized to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From the linked article, DirectX (which of course XNA is built on):

> It appears the future of game development on Microsoft platforms will be exclusively on DirectX. Speaking to Polygon, a Microsoft rep said that "Microsoft is actively investing in DirectX as the unified graphics foundation for all of our platforms, including Windows, Xbox 360, and Windows Phone."

[SharpDX](http://www.sharpdx.org/) is a C# wrapper for DirectX.  Also, most graphics/game engines have DirectX support ([Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), etc).

Comment: Ahh.. I think I missed that part then

Comment: It's strange because, from this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX it seems that microsoft deprecated Managed DirectX in favor of Direct X

Comment: @AndréPena that is odd ... actually WPF/XAML has some features now that wrap DirectX (although I guess it's meant more for business applications than games).

Comment: WPF is horrible for games.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, [Monogame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) - an open-source cross-platform copy of XNA, using Mono, which is the same thing for .Net in general. I say "hopefully" because Mono and Monogame are still in development and some features aren't guaranteed to be recreated.

EDIT: Or something like http://anxframework.codeplex.com/ maybe, which is trying to achieve roughly the same as MonoGame